# QT: How to position a IconTool box on the right side of a window

Tags: c++, qt

QT 4.8, C++

I have a few dock-able icon tool box widgets in my window.

They are all displayed horizontally, on the first line. 
I would like to anchor **(by default)** one of the tool boxes to the **right corner of the window**, as displayed in the pic.

Note that the the tool bar needs to keep anchored as I resize the window. Also, since the tool bars are dock-able, then can be moved or re-ordered by the user.

This is an example I made (with paint, with Visual Studio windows) that exemplify the issue:

[image: Example for a tool box on the top right of a window]

Answer (score -1):

You could probably create a QWidget and use it as a spacer in the left tool bar. Place the spacer after the undo/redo buttons and set the size policy and it's minimum width (or alternatively subclass and re-implement it's size hint) to get a desired behaviour:

```
QWidget spacer;
spacer.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
spacer.setMinimumWidth(200);
fileToolBar->addWidget(&spacer);
```

Comment: it does not really work work well - When I do that, the 1st tool bar becomes too large, and the 2nd one does not attach to the right side of the window. This would only work if my toolbars were fixed and the full window with fix size.